# symfony 1.4: routing based on a partial url

Tags: url-routing, symfony-1.4

I am trying to do the following:

http://www.mydomain.com/Foo/json_bar

in my routing file, I want to say anything going to Foo/json_* it should go to the appropriate action in the action.class.php file

ex:
    Foo/json_bar1 -> public function executeBar1
    Foo/json_bar2 -> public function executeBar2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you could probably write a routing rule like this (untested):

```
my_rule:
  url:   /Foo/json_:action/
  params: { module: myModule, sf_method: json }
```

This, because the `:action` parameter is a "magic" parameter, which sets the action. (Normally you set the `action` parameter in the `params` block.

The `sf_method` is optional, by the way, but it sets the request format as json. That way, any exceptions will also render in JSON, and the correct headers are set for json.

The best practice to do this by the way, would be:
    my_rule:
      url: /Foo/:action.:sf_method
      params: { module: myModule }

In that case you can write a `bar1` action. Going to `/Foo/bar1.html` will render the HTML, and `/Foo/bar1.json` will render a json response. Of course you're free the replace the `:sf_method` with `json`, and set the `sf_method` param, like in my first example.